# Including Shared Libraries (.so) with CMake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I've been trying to include different types of libraries with CMake.

- .a
- .dylib
- .so

I finally, got both the `.a` and `.dylib` to work with this code.

```
find_library(libname NAMES  libcef.dylib PATHS ${libname_PATH})
```

along with this, underneath where I `add_executable` to initialize all my files for the build.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libname})
```

However, I tried using the same code on a `.so` file and it doesn't seem to work.

I get this statement from cmake when I try building.

```
Target "project name" links to item

-- path of file -- 

which is a full-path but not a valid library file name.
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle `.so` files or perhaps I'm not even fully understanding what an `.so` file is. Any input and/or clarification would be much appreciated.

edit:

THEORY-  my theory is because it doesn't have a lib in front of the name of the library name its called ffmpegsumo.so. However, when i try renaming it the file name still saves into the variable name very strange.

Comment: If you haven't got here yet, this might come in handy: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:find_library

Answer (score 1):

The same should work with .so files also, just make sure the required .so file is present at  `${libname_PATH}` which you have given.

find_library treats all types (.a / .so/ .dylib/ .dll) the same way. Problem may be the following

-- path not set up correctly
-- error because of absolute path
-- .so not present
-- If the error is from build (not from configure only) the .so might be corrupt, try replacing it

--Your library does not seem to be valid

Comment: It's very strange I believe I'm getting the correct path because I'm actually extracting an .a library and .dylib library from the same path I provided and it's finding those correctly. However, my theory is because it doesn't have a lib in front of the name of the library name its called `ffmpegsumo.so`

Answer (score 0):

Shared libraries are linked dynamically. That means that your OS will automatically look for and load the .so files when the time comes to run the application. You only need to tell cmake the name of the library and the OS will take care of the rest.

For example, if you want to link to the dynamic library for libSDL.so, you just say: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL)`

As a sanity check, your linker will look to make sure that the SDL library does exist on your computer. That's why you might get a linking error if that library is not available at link-time, even if it's really a dynamic library.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Generally, correct me if I'm wrong but it checks for libraries files in certain places in the MAC directory. `usr/lib/` ect ect However, I'm supplying the .so in my build files to link to. td;lr I think i have to statically link to the library in some manner. I've tried what you suggested though! With the "library not found" in xcode.

Comment: You have to supply a .so file to link to for the linker to be convinced that you're linking to a real library, but it will look for it again at runtime when you launch the program. Static linking might be simpler. Both static and dynamic linking use the same form of `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: `You have to supply a .so file to link to for the linker to be convinced that you're linking to a real library` exactly that's exactly what i'm having trouble with. And agreed about the `target_link_libraries`

Comment: @progenhard To load a dynamic library that is not in default path, you need to setup a special directive to tell this. Not sure if this is the same in in xcode, but in linux, you need to set the enviroment directive `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the directory where you library resides. I guess that in xcode, you need to set up `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`